# Scala: List of pairs to pair of lists

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-collections

I have a list of pairs:

```
val pairs = List("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3)
```

I'd like to convert it to a pair of lists:

```
List("a", "b", "c") -> List(1, 2, 3)
```

Basically, I want the opposite of zip()

Any elegant way of doing so?

Comment: ... but mainly, because Kim Stebel loves downvoting people

Comment: @LuigiPlinge: I don't downvote people, I downvote questions and answers. The people who post them should stop taking it personally. Sadly there is still no way to downvote comments. ;) Besides, I am only one of 3 people who downvoted.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The opposite of zip? What might that be? `unzip` maybe?

```
scala> List("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3).unzip
res0: (List[java.lang.String], List[Int]) = (List(a, b, c),List(1, 2, 3))
```

Comment: Hmmm. Can't see how I missed that :)

Comment: You probably missed it because the documentation of zip does not contain a link to unzip as an inverse. I'll see what I can do about this.